# Choose your R file icon is missing in task-schedule (Add-in)

Tags: r, rstudio

I am trying to schedule my Rcode on daily basis , for this i am using Rstudio add-in and after selecting task scheduler one of the icon is missing - "CHOOSE YOUR FILE" .please help to get resolve the issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: What plugin are you using? Is this a known issue? Can you show some screenshots?

Comment: shedule r script add-in's plugin and and in the plug-in CHOOSE FILE ICON IN the below image 
 https://github.com/bnosac/taskscheduleR/blob/master/vignettes/taskscheduleR-rstudioaddin.png

Comment: Perhaps you can file a github issue.